# Simple feedback contact form is shown only in administrator mode

Tags: feeds, emails

Simple feedback contact form is shown only in administrator mode. How to set it up to make it visible on all pages of my Drupal 7 website? Thank you.

Comment: Check your block UI / Context UI and your permissions

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to give permission to other roles to see or edit simple feedback forms. (**People > Permissions** in the admin menu.) Administrators are usually able to see and edit all content and interfaces regardless of permissions.

Generally speaking, anytime something is stubbornly not showing up, check for any relevant permissions!